# JSON over cURL in PHP not working

Tags: php, json, curl

I have the pages below.

Page `json.php`:

```
$json_data = array(
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name'  => 'Doe',
    'birthdate'  => '12/02/1977',
    'files'      => array(
        array(
            'name'   => 'file1.zip',
            'status' => 'good'
        ),
        array(
            'name'   => 'file2.zip',
            'status' => 'good'
        )
    )
);

$url = 'http://localhost/test.php';

$content = json_encode($json_data);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array(
        "Content-type: application/json",
        "Content-Length: " . strlen($content)
    )
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'json=' . urlencode($content));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status      = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$header_sent = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);

curl_close($curl);

echo $header_sent;
echo '<br>';
echo $status;
echo '<br>';
echo $json_response;
```

Page `test.php`:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

When I’m calling json.php from the browser, I get the following result:

```
POST /json.php HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost Accept: */* Content-type: application/json Content-Length: 150
200

Array
(
)
```

Why can’t I see the POST string I’m trying to send?

**Edit:**

If I don’t set the `Content-type: application/json` header (as per @landons’s comment), I get the following result:

```
POST /ddabvd/widendcm/widendcm-finished.php HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost Accept: */* Content-Length: 150 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
200
Array
(
    [json] => {"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","birthdate":"12\/02\/1977","files":[{"name":
)
```

Comment: What happens when you don't send an application/json Content-type header?

Comment: @landons I get the string truncated. (See my update.)

Comment: Do not use the `$_POST` array for non-multipart and non-urlencoded content. Use `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does not use it's internal request parsing for POST requests if the content type is not set to one of the two official content types that are used when posting forms from inside a browser. (e.g. the only allowed content types are `multipart/form-data`, often used for file uploads, and the default value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

If you want to use a different content-type, you are on your own, e.g. you have to do all the parsing yourself when fetching the request body from `php://input`.

In fact, your content type is currently wrong. It is NOT application/json, because the data reads `json={...}`, which is incorrect when being parsed as json.

Comment: To add to this, you would likely send the content as the body of the message, not as post fields in cURL. This is more common in RESTful service that pass JSON.